# What does this statement mean: "Language is the arbiter of reason, and a lack thereof."

Tags: meaning

I heard this a lot in school and I recently heard it again. What does the sentence mean?

Comment: What research have you done first to find out for yourself?

Comment: arbiter means person of authority. that's about it

Comment: You say you've heard it - where? which country?  Have you seen it written down? If so, where?

Comment: An internet search reveals nothing matching that expression except this question.

Comment: *Reason the true arbiter of language; custom a tyrant; or, Intellect set free from arbitrary authority: in which are shown the absurdities of grammar and rhetoric, their tendency to enslave the mind; the close connection between mental and political bondage; the injustice and impolicy of despotic authority*. James Gilchrist, 
London, Printed for J. Johnson and co., 1814.

Comment: This question was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
The question lacks evidence of research.
Interpretation requests are out of scope.
For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

One definition of **[reason](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reason)** is:

> [mass noun] The power of the mind to think, understand, and form judgements logically

Synonyms of **[arbiter](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/arbiter)** include:

> authority, judge, controller, ...

I would understand the statement:

> "Language is the arbiter of reason, and a lack thereof."

as meaning that the manner in which you explain something (*i.e.* the language you use in your explanation) is a 'judgement' that demonstrates whether your thinking and understanding are logical: if your explanation is logical, then your mental reasoning is logical, and *vice versa*.

Mimicking the original expression:

> The language/explanation serves as a 'judge' or 'authority' on your process of thinking and understanding.

Comment: I would interpret "and a lack thereof" to mean that "language" can be used to inhibit reasonable discussion (as when two people get to talking politics).

Comment: I would interpret "and a lack thereof" to mean that the language used can demonstrate a lack of proper reasoning/understanding.

Comment: Now you're being unreasonable!

Comment: @HotLicks But polotical discussions often are unreasonable - in both senses!

Answer (score 1):

My best bet is that it means something like:

> Language is the means by which we think and communicate rationally, but it can also be used in a way that highlights the speakers poor reasoning.

Comment: i think I have a grasp of the concept now, thanks guys.